# Can't append child to clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to attach div to an element when it is clicked however when I use .appendChild(div), the element I'm trying to attach to is undefined. I'm pretty confused because it's clearly in the DOM as I'm able to detect the click on it, I just can't append to it.

```
var pcells = document.getElementsByClassName('priority-cell');

for (var i=0; i < pcells.length; i++) {
  pcells[i].onclick = function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
       div.style.height = "10px";
       div.style.width = "10px";

       pcells[i].appendChild(div);
  };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. You need to pass in the event details into your handler and use the target property to identify which cell was clicked.

```
var pcells = document.getElementsByClassName('priority-cell');

for (var i=0; i < pcells.length; i++) {
  pcells[i].onclick = function (e) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
       div.style.height = "10px";
       div.style.width = "10px";

       e.target.appendChild(div);
  };
}
```

(JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z3nhprzp/)

Comment: `e.target.appendChild(div);` can be `this.appendChild(div);` - as `this` inside the onclick function is pcells[i] :p

Comment: True but stylistically I prefer to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the  problem is here like：

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i); //5
        console.log(a[i]) //undefined;
    }, 1000)
}
```

If you want to solve, you need closures：

```
   var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        (function(index) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(index); //1,2,3,4,5
                console.log(a[index]) //1,2,3,4,5;
            }, 1000)
        })(i);
    }
```

This is the essence of the problem！

For your code：

```
for (var i=0; i < pcells.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        pcells[index].onclick = function () {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            div.style.height = "10px";
            div.style.width = "10px";

            pcells[index].appendChild(div);
        };
    })(i);  
}
```

by the way,the bast is use 'this' or 'event' like：

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(event);
    //use 'this' or 'event' do something
}
```

Comment: Are you answering a different question ?

Comment: No! I just want let him to know why produce this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var pcells = document.getElementsByClassName('priority-cell');

for (var i=0; i < pcells.length; i++) {
  pcells[i].onclick = function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
       div.style.height = "10px";
       div.style.width = "10px";

       this.appendChild(div);
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="priority-cell">CLICK HERE</div>
```